# To the Basics - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I am so small that you can't see,
The building blocks that make up me.
Yet miles long is the true case,
I'm full of holes, just like lace.
Small changes can be good or bad,
They make you strong or really sad.
In you, your dog, cat, and mouse,
Quite a lot inside your house.
So let's determine now, account,
Grasp the last line's clue and mount.

Comment: So, this was apparently too easy, but I'll give an upvote to anyone who can catch all of the clues. The last one has yet to be noticed.

Comment: Hard to understand which is the last line... If you refer to _Quite a lot inside your house._ it could be referred to the fact that it's said that [almost 80% of the dust in your house is actually skin cells and hair](http://www.livescience.com/32337-is-house-dust-mostly-dead-skin.html). Luckily that's not true (phew!)

Comment: The last clue is in the second to the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is

> DNA

I am so small that you can't see

The building blocks that make up me

> We all are build from DNA blocks, each is few nanometers long

Yet miles long is the true case

> In some sources you can find that unchained DNA sequence is up to 3.85 × 10^8 meters long

I'm full of holes, just like lace

> DNA chain looks likes shoe lace

Small changes can be good or bad

They make you strong or really sad

> Some changes in DNA sequence can be useful (for example, evolution make you adapted to envinronment), or not (mutation can cause diseases)

In you, your dog, cat, and mouse

Quite a lot inside your house

> DNA is in every living (human, animal, plant)

Answer (score 4):

Just an answer to catch the last clue:

> So let's determine now, account

This gives the answer as an

> acronym: "**D**etermine **N**ow, **A**ccount".

Welcome to the fold, fellow riddler! :-) This is what's known as a "lynch mob" clue, because when you've spent ages working out the answer, it can be infuriating (in a good sense) to realise that it was staring you in the face all the time!

Comment: Nicely done. I spent forever trying to figure out how to work it in, so I wanted someone to catch it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it could be...

> DNA

Comment: Why? Give me some explanation as to how it fits into the clues.

Comment: Oh, was writing when you posted...

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

> DNA

I am so small that you can't see,
The building blocks that make up me.

> Without an electronic microscope is quite difficult to actually see the four bases.

Yet miles long is the true case,

> DNA is [quite long](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/1998/StevenChen.shtml)

I'm full of holes, just like lace.

> [image: Yep]

Small changes can be good or bad, 
They make you strong or really sad.

> Little mutations in the DNA can lead to every kind of emotion/status

In you, your dog, cat, and mouse,
Quite a lot inside your house.

> Every living creature has DNA structure

So let's determine now, account,
Grasp the last line's clue and mount.